# Searching 'All' Categories

Tags: categories, search, geofinder

I'm using the Geofinder plugin to search for events taking place in an area.

Each Event is assigned one of five categories. The search works fine when I select a category, but I'm unsure how to get it to search all categories, leaving the value empty doesn't produce the correct results.

Here is the simple code:

```
<select name="categories[]" id="categories">
<option value="">Select All</option>
{exp:channel:categories channel="calendar_events" style="linear"}
<option value="{category_id}">{category_name}</option>
{/exp:channel:categories}
</select>
```

As I say the 'select all' doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had experience with the Geofinder add-on before, however the following should work for anything that uses the Channel Entries API behind the scenes.

```
<select name="categories[]" id="categories">
    <option value="not -1">Select All</option>
    {exp:channel:categories channel="calendar_events" style="linear"}
    <option value="{category_id}">{category_name}</option>
    {/exp:channel:categories}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most efficient code, but you could do this:

```
<select name="categories[]" id="categories">
  <option value="{exp:channel:categories channel='calendar_events' style='linear' backspace='1'}{category_id}|{/exp:channel:categories}">Select All</option>
  {exp:channel:categories channel="calendar_events" style="linear"}
  <option value="{category_id}">{category_name}</option>
  {/exp:channel:categories}
</select>
```